# populate method in mongoose (node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I m trying to use populate( ) in node js.
Well I m trying to access, objectId of one collection into another collection.
for eg., i have collections called Project and events,
where i have schema like this.

Project schema:

```
const projectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    projectName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    dimensions: {
        type: [],
        required: false
    },
    events: {
        [type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: 'EnrichedEvent'
    },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema);
```

Events Schema:

```
const enrichedEventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    projectId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Project',
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["Enriched"],
        required: true
    },
    source: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
});
```

and the routing code for projects to :

```
 const express = require("express");
 const router = express.Router();
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");
 const Project = require("../models/project");

 router.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
     Project.find()
         .populate('source', 'EnrichedEvents') //When i use this populate method, I m not able to GET any events on to browser..
         .exec()
         .then(docs => {
             const response = {
                 count: docs.length,
                 projects: docs.map(doc => {
                     return {
                         projectName: doc.projectName,
                         dimensions: doc.dimensions,
                         events: doc.events,
                         _id: doc._id
                     };
                 })
             };
             res.status(200).json(response);
         })
         .catch(err => {
             console.log(err);
             res.status(500).json({
                 error: err
             });
         });
 });

 router.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
     const project = new Project({
         _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
         projectName: req.body.projectName,
         events: req.body.events
     });
     project
         .save()
         .then(result => {
             console.log(result);
             res.status(201).json({
                 message: "Created project successfully",
                 createdProject: {
                     projectName: result.projectName,
                     _id: result._id,
                     events: result.events,
                 }
             });
         })
         .catch(err => {
             console.log(err);
             res.status(500).json({
                 error: err
             });
         });
 });

 module.exports = router;
```

my problem is I can't auto populate the enriched `eventsId` in projects page.
for eg. Whenever i update events they should appear in projects page.but its not happening. In events page also i am not getting corresponding projectId. please point me in right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populate method takes `FIELD_TO_POPULATE` and `FIELDS_TO_RETURN_FROM_POPULATED_DOC` and you are passing it the reversed way. Also in your project schema you have used `events` for `EnrichedEvent`, so while populating use `events` not `EnrichedEvent`;

Try the following:

From:

`.populate('source', 'EnrichedEvents')`

TO:

`.populate('events', 'EnrichedEvent')`

Edit:

update your schema for `EnrichedEvent`:

```
events: [{
 mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
 ref: 'EnrichedEvent'
}]
```

It should work now.

Comment: Sorry jsut saw that you have defined `EnrichedEvents` as `events` in your project schema. I have updated my answer Please try now and see if it works.

Comment: giving error:   {"error":{"message":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"123456\" at path \"_id\" for model \"EnrichedEvent\"","name":"CastError","stringValue":"\"123456\"","kind":"ObjectId","value":"123456","path":"_id"}}

Comment: `123456` does not seems to be an mongodb ObjectId. That's why its giving error I guess. Can you check if you are receiving correct mongodb ObjectId for events.

Comment: i need to post the data into enrichedEvents schema, then I have to update the eventid into projects, then its working. But i need  projects schema to auto update the eventid with respect to corresponding projectId.

Comment: @darshanan Can you share what are you getting in `console.log(result);` of the post route

Comment: {"count":2,"projects":[{"projectName":"bjaj","dimensions":[],"events":[],"customers":[],"_id":"5aec0e978632a03efaeabf64"},{"projectName":"blownaway","dimensions":[],"events":[],"customers":[],"_id":"5aec0f308632a03efaeabf65"}]} post output

Comment: you are getting empty events array ? or you didn't posted any data.

Comment: I just want projects collection to display with events id. and yeah I posted the data (eventsid) into project collection.

Comment: @darshanan I guess now you must be having some other issue with your code, doesn't seem to be due to populate. Though any more information might be helpful to have more insights on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170354/discussion-between-darshan-a-n-and-farhan-tahir).

Comment: Thanks a  lot @Farhan Tahir

Comment: @darshanan let's reconnect over skype.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use a similar `.populate('...', '...')` method but unsuccessfully. I would use

```
.populate('source').populate('EnrichedEvent')
```

or `('EnrichedEvents')` depending on what you have defined in your schema.